# how to implement custom wysiwyg editor into website

Tags: javascript, php

I'm building a php, javascript powered website and I want to include a powerful wysiwyg editor which can include images, code etc. If possible I want to implement the same one like stackoverflow. how can I do it??

Answer (score 3):

You have to choose dependes on your requirement, and almost all the editors are having same/common features

personally i like [TinyMce](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/)

if you want to see more editors see this [link](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/design/10-best-wysiwyg-text-and-html-editors-for-your-next-project/)

Answer (score 1):

Lucky you there is new lightweight implementation of wysiwyg editor out which uses `contenteditable` attribute and is compatible with different browser versions https://github.com/guardian/scribe. This solution is more customizable than the others.